# funcall vs apply with lambda in elisp

Tags: lambda, elisp, function-pointers

In elisp why does funcalling a lambda work, but applying it raises an error?

```
ELISP> (funcall (lambda ()))
nil
ELISP> (apply (lambda ()))
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: lambda
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My emacs gives another error:

```
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: apply, 1
```

I think it explains everything.

Answer (score 3):

Apply must be given arguments, see the (describe-function) result:

```
apply is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(apply FUNCTION &rest ARGUMENTS)

Call FUNCTION with our remaining args, using our last arg as list of args.
Then return the value FUNCTION returns.
Thus, (apply '+ 1 2 '(3 4)) returns 10.

[back]
```